# How to be fixed my label and button title in autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift

[result of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjoSf.png)

[constraints for first button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUu8D.png)

When I run app in iphone 7plus my button and label title is OK but when I run app in iPhone 5s and small screen size device then title was not display full.

[image: add property scene]

I am making a property app in Swift. I'm facing a problem in design area my label and button title not displaying full. All three button are vertical and space between them. I tried autolayout constraints but my I'm weak in autolayout.

Comment: Give you label left,top,right constraint and a height constraint as >= that will manage it for you. do keep numberoflines=0 for label.

Comment: Can you show how you added autolayout constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution, let button adjust font size:

```
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

And check if the result is acceptable or not.